# How to improve convergence of Taylor series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

I am interested in accurate Taylor series approximations of 1st-order differential equations. For instance:

$$
y' - xy + 3x = 0, y(0) = 5
$$

Using Taylor series directly, it is well-known that the series error is proportional to $\Delta x^n$, where $n$ is the order of the approximation. Therefore, the series is very inaccurate for any point for which $\Delta x$ is large. I can only think of three methods to alleviate this:

- Using a lot of terms for the approximation
- Using some sort of range reduction technique (but I have no idea how to generalize that for an arbitrary differential equation)
- Using multiple taylor series constructed by taking a point computed by a previous taylor series and centering the new taylor series at that point (but isn't this basically just Euler's method/RK?)

Are there any others methods for making accurate Taylor series approximations to a differential equation over a large domain?

Comment: You could try to use the Padé approximants. But while they do not diverge as fast as the partial sums, the accuracy is usually not better. // Methods using the derivatives of the rhs function are not the usual Runge-Kutta methods. // Implicit methods are a little less local than explicit methods.